# roslib reference error

Tags: ros, roslib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did:

```
string fname = ros::package::getPath("foo")
```

and got:

```
test.cpp:(.text+0x424): undefined reference to `ros::package::getPath(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
```

Looking at existing discussions, it seems that this is because of failure to link to roslib.
https://github.com/ros/ros/issues/58

I upgraded all ros packages and tried again but did not work. Your help will be very appreciated.

---

ROS version: Hydro
OS: Ubuntu 12.04
I installed through apt-get

**CMakeList.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

project(ctb)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp std_msgs)

catkin_package(
   INCLUDE_DIRS include
   CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs actionlib_msgs actionlib
)

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(hoge src/PathPlanner/test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(hoge ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

**package.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>roslib</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>roslib</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  <export>
  </export>
</package>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196935/roslib-reference-error/) by [Hiro Ono](https://answers.ros.org/users/20722/hiro-ono/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2014-11-06

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-11-07**:
Please update your question with your `CMakeLists.txt`, `package.xml`, OS, ROS version and whether you've installed from source or debs. Without that, we cannot help you.

**Comment by [Hiro Ono](https://answers.ros.org/users/20722/hiro-ono/) on 2014-11-07**:
I added the requested info. Thank you very much for your help.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-11-09**:
Problem solved?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-11-11**:
Don't know why the whole thread was deleted. I just reverted it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I actually solved by my self. It was CMakeList.txt. I added roslib to find_package and CATKIN_DEPENDS as below and it worked.

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp std_msgs)

catkin_package(
   INCLUDE_DIRS include
   CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs actionlib_msgs actionlib
)
```

---

Originally posted by [Hiro Ono](https://answers.ros.org/users/20722/hiro-ono/) with karma: 146 on 2014-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Azergoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/34694/azergoo/) on 2018-07-13**:
In the example shown I can't see that you added roslib in find_pacakge or CATKIN_DEPENDS, but did I understand you correctly that you meant to include them?

**Comment by [yashtrikannad](https://answers.ros.org/users/45515/yashtrikannad/) on 2020-03-08**:
Yes. Adding roslib to find_package works

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem caused by some precompiled libs; try running `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` to make sure everything installed is up-to-date and delete your workspace lib/devel/install folders and rerun catkin_make to make sure literally everything is recompiled...

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-11-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, ty Giro Ono, you saved me, even if your code was not completely ok... I solved the issue changing CMakelist.txt AND package.xml

In **CMakelist.txt** :

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp  std_msgs rosily)
```

and

```
catkin_package(INCLUDE_DIRS include CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs roslib)
```

In **package.xml**

```
  <build_depend>roslib</build_depend> <run_depend>roslib</run_depend>
```

Pb solved ! (kinetic, c++11, ubuntu 16.04)

---

Originally posted by [jeremie](https://answers.ros.org/users/29873/jeremie/) with karma: 51 on 2018-07-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Azergoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/34694/azergoo/) on 2018-07-13**:
You wrote "rosily" in find_package. Did you mean "roslib" instead?

**Comment by [Azergoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/34694/azergoo/) on 2018-07-13**:
This worked! I added "roslib" to find_package, CATKIN_DEPENDS and in package.xml I added roslib as <build_depend> and <exec_depend>